# Failed to load C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\28.0.3\lib\dx.jar

Tags: java, android

When I try to Run my program as Android Application using latest Eclipse v2018-09 (4.9.0) I am getting following error messages:

> Dex Loader] Failed to load
>   C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\28.0.3\lib\dx.jar
>
> ActivityAndPackageInfo] Unknown error: Unable to build: the file
>   dx.jar was not loaded from the SDK folder!

How do i resolve this issue?

Comment: Eclipse for Android development is no longer supported. Drop it and use Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Robert. But at my work we are not using Android Studio so we are still using Eclipse IDE for all our Mobile testing.

Comment: If you are forced to use Eclipse you should not try to use a recent Android SDK, stick with the old one. And send your boss this link: [Support Ended for Eclipse Android Developer Tools: Nov 2016](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/11/support-ended-for-eclipse-android.html)

Comment: Once again thank you for your reply Robert. Sure I will use older version of Android SDK for time being until we are allow to use Android Studio. Also thanks for the supported link this will definitely help us to convince our manager.